# Create a bean representing a row in a table(Resultset returned due to complex SQL queries) dynamically

Tags: java, sql, reflection, jdbc

Lets take an example i have two tables

```
table1 (
name varchar2,
id int,
customer bit, --or boolean
)

table2 (
name2 varchar2,
id2 int,
dob Date,
)
```

Now the number,name and datatype of column differs. They will be returned based on query like `select * from table1` or `select id2 from table2`

Now is it possible to create a bean which can represent the row returned (in terms of number,name and datatype ) dynamically?

For e.g. for table1 i shuould be able to create something like

```
class Table1{

private String name;
private int id;
private boolean customer;
//Corresponding getters and setters
}
```

same way for table2

Comment: Do you consider some `object relation mapping framework`? like `hibernate`?

Comment: @BkSantiago OP is asking about creating a class dynamically at runtime.

Comment: What's the point in creating a bean dynamically? You're not going to be able to code against its methods beforehand. Can you just use a `Map` of the returned fields?

Comment: If i use Map how will i differentiate between 10000 rows returned by my query ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to create a bean which can represent the row returned
>   (in terms of number,name and datatype ) dynamically?

**Yes**, it is possible in Java. Use `JPA` or `Hibernate`. Which mapped your row with Object.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about creating a class dynamically at runtime. Otherwise, I guess he knows about this trivial answer. So the question is basically about reflection.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be explore the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) and iterate over all columns: using [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) is quite easy create a POJO with field and relative accessors (you can also look at [DynaBean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html)).
Maybe detect column's jdbc type  can be a bit difficult if you are using specific RDBMS type.